# Node.js client-sessions not working when not used as a direct callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using [*express.Router*](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) I'm trying to create a middleware for a specific router in my app that will create and manage a session. This does not work if a session of `client-sessions` is not called directly by `Router().use`. A `undefined` error for the session name occurs.

***The idea (Not working)***

*auth.routes.js*

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import session from 'client-sessions';
import authMiddleware from './auth.middleware';
import authService from './auth.service';

export default () => {
    const router = Router();

    router.use(authMiddleware.createCookie);

    router.use(authMiddleware.authenticate);

    return router;
};
```

*auth.middleware.js*

```
class authMiddleware {

    static createCookie(req, res, next) {
        session({
            cookieName: 'authenticated',
            secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
            duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
            activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000
        });
        next();
    }

    static authenticate(req, res, next) {
        if (req.authenticated) {
            // Check and redirect
        } else {
            req.authenticated.login = false;
        }
        next();
    }
}

export default authMiddleware;
```

***Working version***

Changing the `createCookie` call to a direct creation of the cookie results in 
the above working like so:

*auth.routes.js*

```
`
router.use(
    session({
        cookieName: 'authenticated',
        secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
        duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
        activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000
    })
);
`
```

I'm reasonably new to Node.js so any ideas how the idea could work, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> A undefined error for the session name occurs.

I mean I gotta ask, but you've imported the `client-sessions` library in `auth.middleware.js` right?

Comment: I've tried with such yes. Though in the example above its imported in via `auth.routes.js`. The undefined error exists on the `reg.cookieName`; not the imported variable.